# How to set width of nth column of a dashboard in my bean?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, dashboard

I want to set width of dashboard columns in Primefaces. I can set width in CSS files like this.

```
.ui-dashboard-column:nth-child(3){  
    width: 100px; 
}
```

However, I want to set it in my bean. In JSF file, there is no column element to set style attribute like this example: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/dashboard.xhtml

How can I set width of nth column of dashboard in my bean?

Comment: You may find this answer useful: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320718/primefaces-dashboard-columns-width][1]